# Using Ext JS Plugins in Netzke

Tags: javascript, ruby, extjs, netzke

https://github.com/rbartholomay/ExtJS.ux.HtmlEditor.Plugins is a group 
of ExtJS4 compatible plugins for a htmleditor field.
What would be the  best way of using these plugins in a Netzke form panel that contains a htmleditor field?
More in general, I would like to know how to use ExtJS plugins in Netzke.

Here is some of my code:

```
class DocumentForm < Netzke::Basepack::FormPanel

config do
  { 
    :title => "Edit Document",
     :items => model_fields
  }
end

def model_fields
  [{
    :xtype => 'textfield',
    :field_label => 'Title',
    :name => 'title',
    :allowBlank => false,
    :read_only => false
  },
  {
    xtype: 'htmleditor',
    name: 'body',
    field_label: 'Bodytext',
    height: 300,
    anchor: '98%',
    read_only: false,
  }]
end
```

I would like to make some changes to the toolbar of the htmleditor, but can't figure out how to specify this in Netzke. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It's depend on ExtJS4 API. you can pass any config properties of htmleditor direct to your item hash config like

```
{
  :xtype => :htmleditor,
  :some_config => "some_value"
}
```

because when you use ":xtype" netzke will create ExtJS component with your prefer configuration.It's not Netzke component. (like Netzke::Basepack::Panel is different from :xtype => :panel)

Answer (score 0):

What do you meed "to make some changes" ? I think you want to delete some basic staff from htmleditor such as font, hyperlink, yeah?
This is easy:

```
    xtype => 'htmleditor',
    name => 'body',
    field_label: 'Bodytext',
    height => 300,
    anchor => '98%',
    read_only => false,
    enableColors => false,
    enableAlignments => false,
    enableFont => false,
    enableFontSize => false,
    enableFormat => false,
    enableLists => false
```

I think this is what you are looking for.